# How to remove gaps on a date axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis

How do I clean these empty spaces that I have no data on?

A snippet of my dataset:

```
contratos.dolar <- read.table(text = "
DATA TOTAL IE II PJF PJNF PF VAR 
1 2020-02-28 1003124 178481 -168172 -11901 5497 -3905 <NA> 
2 2020-03-02 643282 140910 -127170 -28232 18187 -3695 -37571 
3 2020-03-03 665899 162927 -138690 -34084 14577 -4770 22017 
4 2020-03-04 688097 195154 -151717 -47994 9912 -5355 32227 
5 2020-03-05 739802 255604 -178552 -82204 8707 -3555 60450 
6 2020-03-06 739802 255604 -178552 -82204 8707 -3555 0", header = TRUE)
```

My code:

```
ggplot(contratos.dolar, aes(x = DATA, y = as.numeric(IE), fill = IE > 0)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  labs(title = "Dolar futuro - Contratos em aberto", subtitle = "Investidor Estrangeiro", caption = format.Date(hoje, "%d/%m/%Y")) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d/%m", expand = c(0,0), limits = c(Sys.Date() - 40, NA), breaks = "2 day") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma, n.breaks = 7) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), plot.caption = element_text(size=10, face="bold.italic")) +
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

And picture of the plot I get:

[image: My ggplt]

Comment: Hi @Fabio. Could you provide a snippet of your data? Just type `dput(contratos.dolar)` in the console and copy the output into your post. As your dataset is probably large use `dput(head(contratos.dolar, 20))` to just copy e.g. the first 20 rows.

Comment: > head(contratos.dolar)
        DATA   TOTAL     IE      II    PJF  PJNF    PF    VAR
1 2020-02-28 1003124 178481 -168172 -11901  5497 -3905   <NA>
2 2020-03-02  643282 140910 -127170 -28232 18187 -3695 -37571
3 2020-03-03  665899 162927 -138690 -34084 14577 -4770  22017
4 2020-03-04  688097 195154 -151717 -47994  9912 -5355  32227
5 2020-03-05  739802 255604 -178552 -82204  8707 -3555  60450
6 2020-03-06  739802 255604 -178552 -82204  8707 -3555      0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the gaps in your date axis you have to convert the date column to a factor. To show only each second date I added a helper function. Try this:

```r
contratos.dolar <- read.table(text = "
DATA TOTAL IE II PJF PJNF PF VAR 
1 2020-02-28 1003124 178481 -168172 -11901 5497 -3905 <NA> 
2 2020-03-02 643282 140910 -127170 -28232 18187 -3695 -37571 
3 2020-03-03 665899 162927 -138690 -34084 14577 -4770 22017 
4 2020-03-04 688097 195154 -151717 -47994 9912 -5355 32227 
5 2020-03-05 739802 255604 -178552 -82204 8707 -3555 60450 
6 2020-03-06 739802 255604 -178552 -82204 8707 -3555 0", header = TRUE)

contratos.dolar$DATA <- as.Date(contratos.dolar$DATA, "%Y-%m-%d")
hoje <- Sys.Date()

contratos.dolar$DATA1 <- factor(format(contratos.dolar$DATA, "%d %m"))
contratos.dolar$DATA1 <- forcats::fct_reorder(contratos.dolar$DATA1, contratos.dolar$DATA)

mybreaks <- function(x) {
  x[seq_along(x) %% 2 == 1]  
}

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(contratos.dolar, aes(x = DATA1, y = as.numeric(IE), fill = IE > 0)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  labs(title = "Dolar futuro - Contratos em aberto", subtitle = "Investidor Estrangeiro", caption = format.Date(hoje, "%d/%m/%Y")) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma, n.breaks = 7) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = mybreaks) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), plot.caption = element_text(size=10, face="bold.italic")) +
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>